# From where did the concept of Juzu' came?

Tags: quran

For example, Juzu' 30 starts with sura `Naba` and ends with sura `Nas`. **My question is, when, how and why did the idea of juzu' came?**

Comment: [Juz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juz%27) is the correct Islamic term

Comment: @Ezati - since this is a practical facilitation that Muslims derived after Islam had been canonized, there is no such thing as a "correct Islamic term" for this :) It is the Arabic term, yes, but there is no harm in using "para" or "thirtieth" or any other term

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I read, the term of juz' was not established in the time of Prophet Mohammad (PBUH). This term and this methodology was introduced by earlier muslims. To be exact, it was introduced by Al-Hajjaj ibn Yusuf when he was the Governor of Iraq in Umayyad caliphate .

My reference is (I'm sorry but it is arabic) :
http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/109885

**Update :**
I found some facts(**in english**) about the role of Al-Hajjaj ibn Yusuf in introducing sections in qur'an in the famous tafsir  , Tafsir al-Qurtubi(Sciences of the Qur'an)  :

http://bewley.virtualave.net/ulum3.html

Comment: Its not that I don't believe you, but as I did not understand your reference (in Arabic), I cannot accept the answer. But of course +1.

Comment: @Mohayemin see the new update of the answer

Comment: The link you cited is quite lengthy. Please quote (using the quote feature) some of the relevant sections in your answer.