# What is the origin of ruku in the Quran?

Tags: quran

I had a [similar question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/from-where-did-the-concept-of-juzu-came) about juzu. Now its about Ruku (as in the [Quranic Subdivisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruku%27#Qur.27anic_subdivision), not the bowing position during *salah*) .

- Was Ruku evolved by the direct order from Allah [ie in the time of the Prophet (Sm)]?

**If not**,

- When was it added to Quran?
- Who was/were the pioneer?
- Why was it added?

Comment: What do you mean by "ruku" do you mean Sajdah? i.e, a specific ayah where you are recommended to perform a Sujood?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: I am sorry. I thought Ruku is a recognized term. I do not mean Sajdah. I mean [Quranic Subdivision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruku'#Qur.27anic_subdivision).

Comment: I never heard this term and don't even have any idea how and when it is applied. I only know that according the subdivisions of Quran the Imams in taraweeh do ruku' after each thoumn (1/8) rubu' (1/4)  etc. of a hizb according the local custom or the strength of the people who pray with them. As where I grow up some of them used to read 1, 2, 3 or even 5 hizbs each night.

Comment: The term is not widely known in Arabic countries, you can read more about the term in this book (In Arabic) https://k-tb.com/book/Quraan03991-%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%AD-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D9%83%D9%88%D8%B9-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%81-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84%D9%88%D9%84%D9%87-%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%A3%D8%AA%D9%87-%D9%88%D8%A3%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%87

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ruku'in the quran is a small section that is grouped up based on the meaning of the ayat that are grouped.

An example of a ruku would be the first 7 ayat of surat baqarah.

The origin of this did not begin during the time of the prophet, in fact it is not even recognized worldwide, hence the reason for people misunderstanding your question.

Organizing the quran in ruku' started in south asia, when people began disecting the quran into sections to prepare for taraweeh in ramadan. they seperated it into 540 section to read in each raka' of the month, hence the name "ruku'."  this beame a guide for people leading prayer to know how many ayat to say, instead of just guessing.

it is not known when exactly this tradition started, but it still used today by color coding certain quran's sections.

sources: ["organization of the quran" By M. Amir Ali.](http://www.discoveringislam.org/organization-of-quran.pdf)